# echo statement not working? Seems to be formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a object in javascript echo'd by PHP, the syntax seems to be correct but it is giving me an error.

The variables I am passing to the object are strings and I have tried putting them in quotes, etc. I also tried creating a JS function to do this and it had similar results.

```
<?PHP 

$TEDS = $db->query("
SELECT a.*
FROM TEDS a
");
//Add each TED location into a javascript array.

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
while($TED = $TEDS->fetch_assoc())
{
   echo 'var pos = {lat: '.$TED['latitude'].', lng: '.$TED['longitude'].'};'; //THIS ECHO STATEMENT IS THE ONE GIVING ME PROBLEMS.
}
echo '</script>';

?>
```

Comment: What's the error? You can probably only have one `pos` var, no? Maybe you should JSON encode the whole thing?

Comment: The error I get on the google chrome console is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

So the comma is throwing an unexpected token. I will try having it named differently.

Comment: That is a JS error. So the PHP is not technically an issue. What is the rendered string(s)?

Comment: var positions = [];var pos = {lat: 45.7165738, lng: -122.6455005};console.log("HIT");var pos = {lat: 39.9414031, lng: -81.601519};console.log("HIT");var pos = {lat: 47.5145695, lng: -122.3554489};console.log("HIT");var pos = {lat: 47.7664257, lng: -122.2098511};console.log("HIT");var pos = {lat: 45.9154793, lng: -95.3720144};console.log("HIT");var pos = {lat: 41.1542148, lng: -88.6541089};console.log("HIT");


Etc etc etc.

I have a 'console.log("HIT"); command after my echo statement, but I removed it from the question because it was not important. But heres contents the script tag @Ivar

Comment: @user3783243 making each name unique did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Ivar The way we set up the page is that this php page is loaded into another php page, so the error is being thrown on line 136 of the main page, but is on line 27 on the page it is written on.

If I remove the one line echo 'var pos = ....' etc etc then the unexpected token error goes away, but I may just be able to ignore it because it still populates my script tag?

Comment: line 136 of the main page is just my header for HTML, the exact line contents is:

</head>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highly likely that one of your latitude values does not have a value, causing it to print something like the following:

```
var pos = {lat:  , lng: 1234}
```

Without a value to go with the property, the JavaScript parser would unexpectedly see the comma. This would greatly explain an unexpected comma syntax error.

So, first of all, you do NOT manually construct JSON. PHP has [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that converts PHP arrays into JSON. Use that to correctly build JSON for you.

Next, your code prints `pos` repeatedly, overriding the previous values. If you only care about the last value, don't print everything. If you do care about all the values, store them in an array:

```
<?php
// Get your TEDS
$teds = $TEDS->fetch_assoc();

// Using array_map to convert the items from latitude-longitude to lat-lng.
$teds_array = array_map(function($ted) {
  return ['lat' => $ted['latitude'], 'lng' => $ted['longitude']];
}, $teds);

// Serialize to JSON
$teds_json = json_encode($teds_array);
?>

// positions will be an array of objects with lat-lng.
var positions = <?php echo $teds_json; ?>
```

Lastly, be careful of XSS. Do not just print unsanitized values like above. Make sure your data is clean before printing it on the page.

Comment: You are right, some of my lats / lngs are empty or null.

Basically my end goal is to get all the lats/lngs and then loop through them and find ones that are near my current position.

Comment: Is it okay to have it in a while loop? So for each row of the record.

AKA while($TED = $TEDS->fetch_assoc())

{ CODE }

How would I loop through each object in var positions = <?php echo $TED_json ?>

Answer (score 0):

i would try to write the full text, after the loop. This way you can build a full json array:

```php
<?PHP 

$TEDS = $db->query("
SELECT a.*
FROM TEDS a
");
//Add each TED location into a javascript array.

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
$text = 'var positions = [';
while($TED = $TEDS->fetch_assoc()) {
   $text .= '{lat: '.$TED['latitude'].', lng: '.$TED['longitude'].'},';
}
// remove last comma
$text = substr($text,0 , strlen($text)-2);
$text .= '];'
echo $text;
echo '</script>';

?>
```

Another way would be to just `json_decode($TED)`.